# Android location tracking

Tags: android, kotlin, location, tracking

I'm a beginner in android development. I need some idea about how can I make an app which can track a phone's live location. I want to use the same app on 2 devices and both of them should be able to track each other. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

the good starting point is https://developer.android.com/training/location where you can find examples and best practices. Depending on your application please consider a suitable strategy (background tracking, geofencing, and impact on the battery). The second thing you have to solve is how to exchange/share information between devices. There are ways how to deal with it. For example, google API, web socket or something else. Sorry for the general answer.